# Pasar un valor de PHP en la misma página

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo una página PHP donde selecciono mediante un combo select 3 valores posibles (1, 2, 3). La variable es idRubro y la obtengo de una tabla mysql:

```
<select id="txtRubro" name="txtRubro">
    <?php
        $rubros = Rubro::all();
        foreach($rubros as $rubro) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rubro->id; ?>">
    <?php
        echo $rubro->descripcion;                                       
    ?>  
    </option>
    <?php                                                               
    }
    ?> 
</select>
```

Lo que necesito es, una vez capturado el ID del Rubro, enviarlo a un switch() en PHP, y de acuerdo a ese valor mostrar una tabla. Todo el código está en la misma página.

De acuerdo a esa elección quiero mostrar una tabla de talles (1-ropa, 2-calzado, 3-accesorios). Para ello utilizo un switch(idRubro) y me muestra la tabla deseada.

Les muestro parte del código, es HTML y adentro PHP:

```
<tbody>                         
<?php                       
    switch($_POST['valor']){
        case 1:                                 
        $talles = Talle::all();
        foreach ($talles as $talle) {
        ?>                      
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $talle->descripcion; ?></td>
```

¿Como envío el valor del SELECT? Intenté con Ajax, envía el valor perfecto, pero cuando lo recibo en una variable $_POST['valor'], no lo puedo usar, ya que no muestra nada.

A esta parte del código la coloco al principio de la página.
Coloco un exit, ya que de lo contrario la respuesta en ajax es todo el código HTML.

```
<?php if( isset($_POST['valor']) ){echo $_POST['valor']; exit;}?>
```

Seguí como ejemplo este enlace donde explican como hacerlo:
http://makitweb.com/how-to-handle-ajax-request-on-the-same-page-php/

La parte con ajax, puede ir sin url, los datos son enviados correctamente. Lo corroboro con la consola de chrome.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  data: {valor: idRubro},     
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  } 
});
```

¿Es esto posible o tengo que buscar otra alternativa?

Comment: Mencionas una variable idRubro pero no aparece en el código que pones, tampoco sale ningún `select` pero se supone que es la fuente del problema. No queda nada claro qué es lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Es parte de un sistema más grande, y por tratar de resumirlo, no me expresé bien.

Comment: A ver si te entiendo, ¿Cuando seleccionas un rubro quieres traer por ajax el detalle para agregarlo como listado en un `tbody`?

Comment: No, simplemente enviar el ID (, 1,2 o 3) del rubro, a un switch en php que está en la misma página, y segun este valor, muestra una tabla u otra.

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer, pero según lo que conseguí entender necesitas algo como esto.

**JavaScript + HTML**

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#contact").submit(function(e){


        // No recargamos la página, *quitalo si no te interesa*
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            //El archivo que lo va a procesar
            url:'show.php',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            // Inicializamos el form data con los valores de nuestro formulario
            data: new FormData($("#contact")[0]),
            // Si hay respuesta la mostramos en el div.
            success:function(CallBack){
                $("#respuesta").html(CallBack);
            }
        });
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--NUESTRO FORMULARIO-->
   <form id="contact">
        <select name="valor" id="valor">
            <option value="1">Ropa</option>
            <option value="2">Calzado</option>
            <option value="3">Accesorios</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Consultar">
    </form>

    <p id="respuesta"></p>
```

Y el código **PHP** seria así

```
<?php 

// Si esta seteada la variable valor
if(isset($_POST['valor'])){
    // Obtenemos el valor
    $valor = $_POST['valor'];
    // Elegimos la opción según el parámetro 
    switch($valor){
        case 1:
        echo "Ropa";
        break;
        case 2:
        echo "Calzado";
        break;
        case 3:
        echo "Accesorios";
        break;
        default:
        echo "";
        break;
    }

}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Se ve que no expresé bien la idea. Te consulto, en la parte de PHP, el switch($valor) está adentro del código HTML, ya que muestro una tabla. Y ahí es donde $valor no trae nada. Ese es el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es atacar la misma url desde ajax creo debes colocar la url en el ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'index.php',
  data: 'rubro=1';
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

todo el principio del codigo php debe ser al inicio y finalizas con exit(); para terminar con el script y no mostrar ni hacer nada de lo que sigue.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['rubro'])) {
//muestro esto
    echo $_POST['rubro'];
    exit();
}
//despues de aqui todo tu codigo a mostrar si no existe el POST rubro
?>
```

Comment: Esto para mi no tiene ningun sentido hay mejores formas de hacerlo